# Laravel: Grab nested items

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to get an item from a collection like:

```
[
{
"id": 17,
"corretora_id": 1,
"user_id": 2,
"order": null,
"nome": "Johnny English",
"telefone": "(11)0070-0070",
"celular": "(00)70070-0700",
"email": "j@mi7.uk",
"obs": "Lorem ipsum",
"img_lead": "1534353433.png",
"created_at": "2018-08-15 17:17:14",
"updated_at": "2018-08-15 21:30:48",
"atendimentos": [
    {
        "id": 22,
        "lead_id": 17,
        "dataAgendamento": "2018-08-16 09:00:00",
        "user_id": 2,
        "comentarios": "Alea jacta est",
        "created_at": "2018-08-15 20:48:07",
        "updated_at": "2018-08-15 20:48:07"
    }
]
},
```

...

This returns a variable called $leads witch a loop trough a foreach on my blade page. It looks like a vertical timeline as showing bellow:

```
 Johnny English
Fixo: (11)0070-0070   Celular: (00)70070-0700

[{"id":22,"lead_id":17,"dataAgendamento":"2018-08-16 09:00:00","user_id":2,"comentarios":"Realmente \u00e9 o homem mais burro do mundo. QUer um plano de sa\u00fade para agentes secretos em nome de 007.\nPediu pra ligar amanh\u00e3","created_at":"2018-08-15 20:48:07","updated_at":"2018-08-15 20:48:07"}]
```

I need to show only the "comentarios" item but the syntax {{ $lead->atendimentos->comentarios }} doesen´t work, of course.
It is showing cause I´ve coded:  {{ $lead->atendimentos }}

Let me show my controller part of code:

```
public function index()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $corretora = Corretora::where('id', '=', $user->corretora_id)->first();
        $leads = Lead::where('corretora_id', '=', $corretora->id)
            ->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->with('atendimentos')
            ->get();
            // return $leads;
        return view('layouts.atendimentos.index')->withLeads($leads);
    }
```

... and the blade part:

```
 <div class="col-6">
            @if($leads->isEmpty())
                    Não há trabalho pra você hoje!
            @endif
            @foreach($leads as $lead)
                <atendimento 
                id={{ $lead->id }} 
                image={{ asset('images/' . $lead->img_lead) }} 
                nome="{{ $lead->nome }}" 
                email="{{ $lead->email }}" 
                telefone="{{ $lead->telefone }}" 
                celular="{{ $lead->celular }}" 
                obs="{{ $lead->obs }}" 
                comentarios="{{ $lead->atendimentos }}"></atendimento>
            @endforeach
        </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your collection, the `$lead->atendimentos` is an array of one object item. As such to access the `comentarios` value you need to use the index 0.

In this case it becomes

```
{{ count($lead->atendimentos) > 0 ? $lead->atendimentos[0]->comentarios : 'No comentarios' }}
```

Comment: Yes, but it returns only the first if is not empty and an error if is empty.

Comment: I have edited the post to address a case where the array is empty which outputs the string 'No comentarios'  if the array is empty